# Can't define Ui_MainWindow in pyqt

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

When ever I try to compile the following code I get the error:
    class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
NameError: name 'Ui_MainWindow' is not defined

My code is:

```
    import sys
import clientGUI
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        clientGUI.Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `Ui_MainWindow` is defined in `clientGUI`, so you need to reference it as

```
class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, clientGUI.Ui_MainWindow):
    ...
```

Or you can import it as:

```
from clientGUI import Ui_MainWindow
```

and then use this name in code.

See more info about modules in [Python 3 tutorial](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/modules.html)